# setCursor not woking correctly during drag'n'drop

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, awt

To create a custom cursor in **java** i use:

```
window.setCursor(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.setDefaultCursor(image,Point,"name"));
```

it works really fine but:

When I try it with **Drag & Drop** the cursor doesn't override the default System Cursor:

In windows for example the cursor remains the default Windows Drag & Drop cursor until the mouse is released and finally the custom cursor appears.  Why this happens and how I can override the System default cursor in this situation?

For example in Eclipse when I drag & drop one item the cursor changes to a custom eclipse cursor.

Comment: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit.setDefaultCursor(image,Point,"name")`  There is at least two reasons that noise would not compile.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  And please check that the MCVE both compiles and demonstrates the problem.